# Migrating AudioKit from version 2 to version 4

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm working on updating this project:
https://github.com/elslooo/guitar-tuner

The author wrote on Swift 3 and uses AudioKit 2.2. I have already moved to Swift 4 and would like to migrate to AudioKit latest version 4.2. I look at the AudioKit [migration guide](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/Documentation/MigrationGuide.md), but there it's mentioned only that's a complete rewrite from version 2.

The major compiler errors I'm getting now are:

- Use of undeclared type 'AKAudioAnalyzer'
- Use of undeclared type 'AKAudioPlot'
- Use of unresolved identifier 'AKManager'
- Value of type 'AudioPlot' has no member .... (several properties)
- Use of unresolved identifier 'AKOrchestra'

Could you please point me to some AudioKit documents or references where I can find the new equivalent classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AudioKit 3 was a complete rewrite and there is no real upgrade path, but:

- AKAudioAnalyzer -> AKFrequencyTracker
- AKAudioPlot -> AKNodeOutputPlot
- AKMananger -> AudioKit
- AKOrchestra -> Unused

I suggest you use one of these projects for a starting point for the internals anyway:

- https://github.com/comyar/TuningFork
- https://github.com/swiftingio/SingTest

They are at least based in AudioKit 3 and should be easier to upgrade to AK4.

We'd love to highlight your rewrite here:

- https://audiokitpro.com/project-ideas/

Comment: Also wanted to add there is a Migration Guide now, so its a good thing to keep an eye on going forward: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/Documentation/MigrationGuide.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aurelius. I will get back here when I'm done or if I have any questions.

Comment: Hello @aure, I have a couple of questions:
- I didn't find any class called AKNodePlot
- Which method in AudioKit can be used to replace AKManager.shared().enableAudioInput()?

Thanks for now. As soon as I finish the migration I will highlight my rewrite where you pointed.

Comment: @LucianoSclovsky I updated my answer to AKNodeOutputPlot. Typing AKPlot in Xcode should give autocomplete choices.  Just use AKMicrophone to enable input.